# How do I access a changing variable from another class ? ( e.g. level count )

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, global-variables

I have two scenes. Scene A is the game scene, where the `level` variable of type `int` changes. In class B I want to get the variable.

What I've got now is the following :

--------------------------------- LevelDone.m ---------------------------------

```
HelloWorldLayer *object = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc]init];

        int pointsForZeroStars = [[requiredPoints objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
        int pointsForOneStar = [[requiredPoints objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
        int pointsForTwoStars = [[requiredPoints objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];
        int pointsForThreeStars = [[requiredPoints objectAtIndex:3] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"HEALTH = %d",object.health);
        CCSprite *levelDoneWindow;         
        if ( object.health < pointsForZeroStars){
            NSLog(@"should be 0 stars");
            levelDoneWindow = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"leveldonescreen0stars.png"];
        }
```

NSLog returns the initial value of `health` which is 100, when actually it is something smaller than 100.

In the game class I call `pushscene` in order to call the LevelDone scene:

----------------------------- HelloWorldLayer.m (GAME SCENE) -------------------------------------

```
else{

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[LevelDone node]];
    [self generateLevelFromPlist:level];


}
```

The `-generateFromPlist` method resets the health to 100. But it is certainly called after the `NSLog` method in my `LevelDone.m` class, which nonetheless prints out that `health` is 100.

How do I retrieve the value of this variable properly ?

Comment: Where are you setting/updating the value of `health?` The error is not in the code shown here, but most likely in the HelloWorldLayer class.

Comment: Sounds great/bad ! Should not the `pushScene` method pause all selectors and methods ? I have a selector running which runs in the interval of 1 second. But it only reduces the health. Actually the following method `[self generateLevelFromPlist:level];` sets it to 100 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a singleton to manage global values.

http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

Basically, you can create properties in that singleton class, and it will "persist" throughout the game no matter what scene you are in etc.

Comment: All right... thank you ... It's probably a good approach. But what exactly should I do ? This singleton can't store the changing `health` variable from my `game` class either, right ?

Comment: Uh, of course it can. If you change the value from 100 to 50, it will remain 50 forever.. until you change it again of course. Nothing is reset.

Comment: Yes but I need to get it from the game class anyway don't I ? So if it changes there it will do so in my singleton class... Or did I misunderstand something ?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How are you reducing the object's health?

Comment: it is definitely the `-generateLevelFromPlist` method, where I set the health to 100. I tried to change the value to 50 and the `LevelDone` class retrieved that very value. But why is the function called anyway ?

Comment: The value in the .plist will never change from 100. For it to truly change, you have to save the .plist dictionary whenever you make changes. Saving, however, might not be the best choice here. All you want is some value you can read/write all the time. Thus, a singleton would be very useful...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `health` property of the HelloWorldLayer is actually being updated correctly? If so, I'd suspect (and, again, just guessing, as the error does not appear to be in the provided code itself) that the variable you're changing within the HelloWorldLayer is not the same as the property you're accessing with `object.health` -- perhaps a scope issue is at play here (ie, the selector is affecting a local `health` variable, but not the instance variable itself).

Comment: If I try to set the level variable it does not work either. Maybe it is just a horrendous cycle that is called all over again and does terrible things, I am really desperate right now !

Comment: there is no local variable of health, as it is used as a global variable only ...